# cs50 pset3 lockin function

Tags: c, cs50

i did this implementation of lockin function and it seems to work perfectly in every case i could come up with but when i submit it cs50 says:
":( lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle
lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs
:( lock_pairs skips middle pair if it creates a cycle
lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs"

thats my code

```
// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // initialising an array with all the untargted candidates (no arrows pointing to them)
    bool untargeted[candidate_count];
    // initialising a variable to keep track of how many sources (untargted candidates)
    int untar = 0;

    // chacking all as untargeted
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        untargeted[i] = true;
        untar++;
    }

    // iterating over all pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        // checking if the loser is the only untargeted candidate to prevent cycles
        if (!(untargeted[pairs[i].loser] && untar == 1))
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
            // checking if loser was untargted to mark them as a targeted
            if (untargeted[pairs[i].loser])
            {
                untar--;
                untargeted[pairs[i].loser] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

i already submitted and fine with losing the 2 marks i just need to know whats wrong with my code

Comment: Online judging systems (like the automated system used by CS50) aren't really good resources for learning programming. They don't teach you the principles needed to become a good programmer, they don't teach you debugging, and they tend to not show the data used which means it's hard to impossible to debug anyway. Invest in books and take real classes instead.

Comment: "i did this implementation of lockin function" and would you like to tell what it is supposed to do?